# Multi-Argument Typemaps and Wrapping Pointers

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

I've mapped a series of arguments using multi-arguments typemaps to `byte[]` between C and Java but whenever I call `ReleaseByteArray` in the `wrapper`, I get the following error...

> Error in `java': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00007f1a70174610 ***
>   ======= Backtrace: =========
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7d023)[0x7f1a75da9023]
>   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_74/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(+0x6d9ab6)[0x7f1a75425ab6]
>   /usr/lib/libtesting.so(Java_com_testing_foo_jni_1foo+0x639)[0x7f1a192d03f6]
>   [0x7f1a60dfa994]

Additionally, if I remove the release calls, foo returns but the output array (arg1) has not been modified on return probably because ReleaseByteArray isn't called.

My 'swigging' is not the best but I've successfully wrapped this function using carrays and passing individual arguments.  I really want to pass only three byte arrays though from Java and want to use the multi-argument typemaps and can't find the source of the errors.

Valgrind shows no memory errors or leaks in the C when using from C.

Could this be an issue with garbage collection in Java?  Thread issue?

Thanks for any guidance!  Hope my typemapping example helps someone else.

(All code is below)

I have the following function in C to wrap with SWIG:

```
int foo(
          unsigned char *out, unsigned long long *out_len,
          const unsigned char *a, unsigned long long alen,
          const unsigned char *b
        )
```

Calling foo from Java, out is supplied at the proper size and should be filled with bytes on return...

```
void foo(byte[] out, byte[] a, byte[] b) <-- out should be filled on return.
```

My typemap for "out": (multi-argument structure from swig docs).  I have similar maps for the other arguments.

```
/* unsigned char *, unsigned long long * */
%typemap(jni) (unsigned char *out, unsigned long long *out_len)  "jbyteArray"
%typemap(jtype) (unsigned char *out, unsigned long long *out_len)     "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) (unsigned char *out, unsigned long long *out_len)    "byte[]"
%typemap(in,numinputs=1) (unsigned char *out, unsigned long long *out_len){
  $1 = JCALL2(GetByteArrayElements, jenv, $input, 0);
  unsigned long long tp = JCALL1(GetArrayLength, jenv, jarg1);
  $2 = &tp;
 }
%typemap(argout) (unsigned char *out, unsigned long long *out_len){
  JCALL3(ReleaseByteArrayElements, jenv, $input, (jbyte *) $1, 0);
 }
%typemap(javain) (unsigned char *out, unsigned long long *out_len)"$javainput"
/* Prevent default freearg typemap from being used */
%typemap(freearg) (unsigned char *out, unsigned long long *out_len)""


Generated wrapper.c (partial)

SWIGEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_testing_foo_jni_1foo(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jbyteArray jarg1, jbyteArray jarg3....
.
.
.
{
   arg1 = (*jenv)->GetByteArrayElements(jenv, jarg1, 0);  <-- get
   unsigned long long tp = (*jenv)->GetArrayLength(jenv, jarg1);
   arg2 = &tp;
}
.
.
.
result = (int)foo(arg1,arg2,...   <-- call foo
jresult = (jint)result; 

***THESE GENERATE THE ERROR.*** 

  {
    (*jenv)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jenv, jarg1, (jbyte *) arg1, 0);  <-- release
  }
  {
    (*jenv)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jenv, jarg3, (jbyte *) arg3, 0);
  }
  {
    (*jenv)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jenv, jarg5, (jbyte *) arg5, 0);
  }
  .
  .
  .


***END SECTION***

  return jresult;
```